# Javascript Call to Google Places API Fails

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to implement an address lookup using the Google Places API for a non-profit I work for.  It was working at one point for a single address (in so far as when you started to type the address, it would provide suggestions that were clickable and would fill the form).

Now, as I try to break the information into components (street number, street name, etc) and place the values into different fields, the process breaks.  It doesn't seem to be firing the fillInAddress function at all upon 'place_changed'.

I know this is something really obvious, but my developer coworker and I are stumped.

Any suggestions on how to get the fillInAddress function to fire properly and fill the form would be appreciated.  Code Below:

```
<script>
    var componentForm;
    var options;
    var autocomplete;
    var place;

    function fillInAddress() {
        place = autocomplete.getPlace();
        for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
            var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
            if (componentForm[addressType]) {
                var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
                if (addressType == "street_number") {
                    document.getElementById('StreetNumber').value = val;
                }
                else if (addressType == "route") {
                    document.getElementById('StreetName').value = val.substring(0, val.lastIndexOf(" "));
                    document.getElementById('StreetType').value = val.substring(val.lastIndexOf(" ") + 1);
                }
                else if (addressType == "postal_code") {
                    document.getElementById('PostalCode').value = val;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function GetAddresses() {
        componentForm = {
            'street_number': 'long_name',
            'route': 'long_name',
            'locality': 'long_name',
            'administrative_area_level_1': 'short_name',
            'country': 'long_name',
            'postal_code': 'short_name'
        };

        options = {
            componentRestrictions: { country: 'ca' }
        };
        var input = document.getElementById('AddressLookup');

        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(49.179794, -123.127395);

        autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));

        autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress());
    }
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?output=xml&libraries=places&key=<KEY_HERE>&callback=GetAddresses" async defer ></script>
```

Here is the HTML Code and the AddressLookup field is the one tied to the javascript:

```
<!-- Home Address -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 sectionHeader">
                Home Address: <label class="requiredOption">&nbsp;*</label><asp:label id="validationAddress" CssClass="requiredMissed" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 sectionDescription">
                Please enter your address.
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="Apartment" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" /><br />
                        <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Apartment</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 sectionSelections">
                        <asp:TextBox id="AddressLookup" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" PlaceHolder="Address, City, Province, Postal Code"  ClientIDMode="Static" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" /><br />
                        <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Address Search</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections"></div>
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="StreetNumber" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="true" /><br />
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">House Number</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="StreetName" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="true" /><br />
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Street Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="StreetType" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="true" /><br />
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Street Type</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="City" CssClass="addressSize" Text="Richmond"  runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" /><br />
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">City</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="Province" CssClass="addressSize" Text="BC" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" /><br /> 
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Province</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 sectionSelections">
                <asp:TextBox ID="PostalCode" CssClass="addressSize" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="false" /><br /> 
                <label class="datePicker nameLabelSize">Postal Code</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I hope this is enough information and details to get your expert help, but please feel free to ask questions and I'll check back regularly!

Thank you in advance for any assistance you might be able to provide.

Regards,

Jonathan

EDIT:

I should mention, when running in debug mode from Visual Studio, the page loads.  I can click into the addresslookup textbox and when I start to type, Google Places will start filling in suggestions without problem.  All that is great.  The challenge comes when clicking on one of the items in the suggestion list.  At that point the full address appears within the addresslookup textbox, but the individual textboxes do not fill at all.  I tried removing the enabled=false to see if that might be the cause from a "client-side" vs "server-side" thing.  Same thing for having the fields as hidden, since that moves the contents to the server and away from the client.  So that hidden was removed too.  These didn't help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Just in case you haven't read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'd invite you to read it. Since this is a javascript issue, if you could the remove the asp tags and simplify it into a HTML/JavaScript problem instead more people would be able to help.

Comment: firstly, change `autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress());` to `autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);` - you want to pass a function to addListener, not the result of calling a function

Comment: Jaromanda X:  You are brilliant.  Thank you so much, for some reason, I just couldn't see that!  How can I mark this as completed, and give you credit for your brilliant, simple, and efficient answer?     Sir Rufo:  Thank you for correcting my tags!